# Change the answer "to" the question number 1

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I saw somebody answered "answer to the question" is the normal grammatical form.
So is it always correct to use "answer to"?

- Change the answer to the first question.
- You have the wrong answer to the second question.
- You have the right answer to the question A-1.

Are they all correct?

Comment: Example #1 is standard AE, but needs more to fill out any meaning. For example, "Change the answer to the first question from B to E." Or "Change the answer to the first question. You answered B where the expected answer is E."

Answer (score 2):

"answer" can be a noun or a verb

Examples

Please *answer* this question.  (verb)

Please give an *answer* to this question.  (noun)

---

So, yes, we change the answer to a question.

Comment: I think all three examples are correct, except I would omit the "the" from the last "question" example:

"You have the right answer to question A-1."

Comment: @4ndy - I agree.

Answer (score -4):

No. All of your examples are not correct. Recommend changes as follows. Or the like. The target for the last two examples is the word "Answer," and answers are responses to questions. See Below.

```
You have the wrong answer for the second question.
You have the right answer for question A-1.
```

It is my belief that the first example given above is fine because the target word "to" is applied to the word "question," rather than the word "answer," if that makes any sense. I am the architect of many test taking applications which were designed for higher education in America. The verbiage with regards to the words "question," and "answer," can be intricate and confusing.

Comment: In English, "the answer to the question" is perfectly grammatically correct. In American this may not be the case. In Britain, "the answer for the question" would sound wrong.